# Does delegate have function which is executed every time app comes from background

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I have application with lot of view controllers and on every time when app comes from background I have to make some request to server and reinitialise some global variables. At the moment I am doing this by repeating code in every view controller in didViewLoad but I wonder is there way to this in delegate to avoid repeating on 10 places ? ( I check didFinishLuanchingWithOptions in delegate but it is called only first time not when app comes from background ).

Comment: Have you looked at the `UIApplicationDelegate` documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to look at these two:

```
applicationDidBecomeActive
```

And

```
applicationWillEnterForeground
```

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground:) for more details.